# Using the phrase 'X to come' in Italian

Tags: grammar, translation

How would I be able to translate the phrase '*X* to come' to use in Italian? What counterpart exists for it in the language?

***Example:***

> *'worse to come'*
>
> Over in the centre, we've got worse to come in terms of weather: quite a few thunderstorms throughout the middle part of the country accompanied by very strong rain, but still a little bit of sunshine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can add that "Il peggio deve ancora venire" is a common, idiomatic way of saying "The worst is yet to come", so your sentence might be rephrased as something like:

> Nel centro, per quanto riguarda il tempo, il peggio deve ancora venire [...]

Comment: I think this is a perfect translation of both "The worst is yet to come" and of "we've got worse to come". I'm afraid that "dobbiamo aspettarci un tempo più brutto" - although it is correct - does not convey the same "emotion".

Answer (score 3):

In some situations it can be translated literally with *"a venire"*, as in *"years to come"* -> *"anni a venire"*. This however works mainly with time expressions (I'm sorry I cannot think of an hard and fast rule).

In all other cases you have to translate less literally by using periphrases and in generally restructuring the sentence. This is how I'd translate your example sentence:

> Nel centro dobbiamo aspettarci un tempo più brutto: parecchie tempeste lungo la parte mediana del paese accompagnate da pioggia molto forte, con tuttavia degli sprazzi di sereno.

As you can see I translated *"We've got worse to come in terms of weather"* as *"Dobbiamo aspettarci un tempo più brutto"* that is *"we should expect a worse weather"*.

(This sentence sounds a little clunky to me honestly, I probably would rather say *"delle giornate più brutte"* but I wanted to stay as close as possible to the example you provided).